# ORA-04063: type body "TAREA7.PROFESOR" has errors

Tags: sql, oracle, objeto, sobrecarga

He creado siguientes tipos con un constructor especifico

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE MiembroEscolar AS OBJECT (

  codigo INTEGER,

  dni VARCHAR2(10),

  nombre VARCHAR2(30),

  apellidos VARCHAR2(30),

  sexo VARCHAR2(1),

  fecha_nac DATE)

NOT FINAL;

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Profesor UNDER MiembroEscolar (

  especialidad VARCHAR2(20),

  antiguedad INTEGER,

CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION Profesor(ID INTEGER, nombre VARCHAR2, PrimerApellido    VARCHAR2, SegundoApellido VARCHAR2, ESPECIALIDAD VARCHAR2)
    RETURN SELF AS RESULT,

MEMBER PROCEDURE getNombreCompleto(p Profesor));

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY Profesor AS

CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION Profesor (ID INTEGER, nombre VARCHAR2, PrimerApellido VARCHAR2, SegundoApellido VARCHAR2, ESPECIALIDAD VARCHAR2)
    RETURN SELF AS RESULT
   
IS
      
BEGIN
         
  SELF.codigo:=ID;
         
  SELF.nombre:=nombre;
         
  SELF.apellidos:= PrimerApellido||' '||SegundoApellido;
         
  SELF.especialidad:=ESPECIALIDAD;
         
  SELF.dni:=NULL;
         
  SELF.sexo:=NULL;

  SELF.fecha_nac:=NULL;
         
  SELF.antiguedad:=0;
         
RETURN;
      
END;

MEMBER PROCEDURE getNombreCompleto(p Profesor) IS

   BEGIN
    
     dbms_output.put_line(p.apellidos|' '|p.nombre);
   
   END;

/
```

Al ir a insertar en una tabla de objetos ya creada llamada profesorado y utilizar el creado me da error, si uso el generado por Oracle no hay ningún problema

```
BEGIN

INSERT INTO Profesorado VALUES (Profesor(3, 'JAVIER', 'JIMENEZ', 'HERNANDO', 'LENGUA'));

END;
```

me da el error ORA-04063: type body "TAREA7.PROFESOR" has errors, ¿Cuál o cuales son los errores?, he realizado muchos cambios pero sigue saliendome el mismo error.
gracias por vuestra ayuda

Uso Oracle Database 11g EXPRESS EDITION
Cuando le pongo show errors me dice comando invalido
Cuando introduzco los tipos no indica ningún error de compilación

Comment: Hola! ¿Versión de Oracle? Lo otro, qué sale cuando le das `show errors` inmediatamente después de intentar crear estos tipos? Recuerda añadir la info yendo a [edit] la pregunta, que en los comentarios no se entiende el código